# Make System.currentTimeMillis() stop counting?

Tags: java, time

In my code I have a timer that is running at the top that has the value of `System.currentTimeMillis()/1000.0`.  When the game starts, a value called `tStart` is set to `System.currentTimeMillis` and when the game ends a value called `tEnd` is set to `System.currentTimeMillis()`.  When the game ends, the time value is changed from `System.currentTimeMillis()` to `tEnd - tStart`, but rather than staying at one value it keeps counting.  How do I stop it?

Comment: the question is hard to understand. Can you provide some code example?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately we cannot help you until you provide us with an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You cant do that. You should save the value of  tEnd - tStart in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot stop the system clock.
You can find third party stopwatch classes that will do what you want.

Like [Apache](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/), which has org.apache.commons.lang.time.StopWatch

More generally, you need to save your tStart and tEnd into variables, and if you ever need to start the timer again and relate the previous lap to the new lap, just find the offset (tStart2 - tEnd)

Answer (score 0):

currentTimeMillis displays the current time in milliseconds. You can not make it stop, only read it. 
Can you show your code? It does seem like this should still work.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This sort of answers are supposed to be left as comments. I know you don't have enough reputation to leave comments, but it doesn't mean you need to flood. Add some code and/or links to documentation to make this more answer-like.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you should try to explain, what time do you exactly want to receive.
For the easiest purposes you could use this simple implementation of Stopwatch (and eventually extend it's functionality by required functions):

```
public class Stopwatch {

    private long startTime;
    private long endTime;
    private boolean running;

    public Stopwatch(){

    }

    public void start(){
        this.startTime = System.nanoTime();
        running = true;
    }

    public void stop(){
        this.endTime = System.nanoTime();
        running = false;
    }

    public long getElapsedTime(){
        return (this.running ? System.nanoTime() : this.endTime) - this.startTime;
    }

    public boolean isRunning(){
        return this.running;
    }

    public void reset(){
        this.startTime = 0L;
        this.endTime = 0L;
    }

}
```